# Access is denied. JavaScript error on request to secured page

Tags: javascript, ajax, https, xmlhttprequest

On page `SomePage.aspx`, by JavaScript code (XMLHttpRequest) I call `SecuredPage.aspx` used next code:

```
    var httpRequest = GetXmlHttp();
    var url = "https://myhost.com/SecuredPage.aspx";

    var params = "param1=" + document.getElementById('param1').value +
                "&param2=" + document.getElementById('param2').value;

    httpRequest.open("POST", url, true);
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        //Call a function when the state changes.
        if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {
            alert(httpRequest.responseText);
        }
    }
    httpRequest.send(params); // HERE ACCESS IS DENIED.

    //---------------------------------------------
    function GetXmlHttp() {
        var xmlhttp = false;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else if (window.ActiveXObject)
        // Code for Internet Explorer.
        {
            try {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e) {
                try {
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (E) {
                    xmlhttp = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return xmlhttp;
    }
```

It throws an *Access is denied* error. If send to http (http://myhost.com/SecuredPage.aspx), it works fine.

How is it possible to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wish to fetch an [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) page via Ajax you need to do it from an HTTPS page on the same domain, there is no other way, as long as you use Ajax. This is because of [the same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

That said, there are plenty of ways to do this not using Ajax, [for instance you can use frames](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes).

Another way is to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), but this requires that you are fetching, well, JSON :)

A third way, that tends not to be very useful for production websites, but still can be fun to tinker around with, is to use [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) as a proxy.

Lastly you can always set up a serverside proxy of your own, so that you call an HTTP address that fetches the HTTPS page and sends it on, but this is rarely a good solution if it can be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the browser considers `http` and `https` as 2 different sites/domains, and therefore you have to adhere to the same origin policy.

```
Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.
```

One way to solve it is using jsonp.

Answer (score 1):

As it's been said, your problem is that your browser sees this as a cross domain request.  Another way to accommodate this is to set up a crossdomain.xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="myhost.com" />
  <allow-access-from domain="ourhost.com" />
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

I'm *not* an expert on this method, but I have used it successfully.  Other domains can be added by adding more `allow-access-from` tags.  You may need to do some fiddling.  YMMV.

Comment: where I should put/use this XML file?

Comment: It goes at the siteroot.  It should be accessible at myhost.com/crossdomain.xml

Comment: If I need two domains like myhost.com and ourhost.com, how should I add it to xml file!? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks! Just uploaded to server root and Unfortunately same error - Access is denied :(((

Comment: I had the same problem as @ihorko and needed to do one more step to get it to work out. (It was fine in Chrome and friends even without crossdomain.xml but IE was not happy.) Visit https://forum.jquery.com/topic/cross-domain-ajax-and-ie and there is a block of code you can drop in to fix the issue.